# readr spec() not updating after variable names and types are changed

Tags: r, readr

I'm doing some data wrangling on proprietary data and having a problem with `spec()` not updating after I make changes to variable names or types. I'll use `mtcars` as an example of what I'm experiencing. Can anyone let me know why this is happening and how to get it to update?

```
library(tidyverse)

# use read_csv to read in original file
mtcars_orig <- read_csv(readr_example("mtcars.csv"))
spec(mtcars_orig) # check variable types

# make work file
mtcars_work <- mtcars_orig 

# rename mpg variable
mtcars_work <- rename(mtcars_work, m_p_g = mpg)
str(mtcars_work) # m_p_g name updates
spec(mtcars_work) # mpg name doesn't update

# change cyl to character type
mtcars_work$cyl <- as.character(mtcars_work$cyl)
str(mtcars_work$cyl) # variable type updates
spec(mtcars_work) # variable type doesn't update
```

Comment: I'm `spec`-ulating here, but I suspect that it isn't supposed to update. The column specification may be intended to represent only how the file was originally read into R, and so things that happen after that are outside it's purview.

Comment: ...additionally, since the spec is an attribute, constantly modifying it to keep up would likely trigger tons of copying.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for spec-ulating. Apparently I was thinking of it incorrectly.